# Problem during update field LIPS-LFIMG in standard table

Tags: abap, sap-erp

All the flows seen like okay, however when pass through the call function, the update also failed and the field that need to be update not updated, not sure where is the problem, can someone help me with this problem? do i miss any step?

Error message Log in LT_PROT

[image: press here to view]

```
DATA: LT_PROT LIKE PROTT OCCURS 10 WITH HEADER LINE.
  DATA: LT_VBPOK  LIKE VBPOK OCCURS 500  WITH HEADER LINE.
  DATA: LS_VBKOK  LIKE VBKOK.
  DATA: GT_LIPS LIKE LT_LIPS.
  DATA: WA_LIPS TYPE LTY_LIPS.


  DATA: EF_ERROR_ANY_0                TYPE C,
        EF_ERROR_IN_ITEM_DELETION_0   TYPE C,
        EF_ERROR_IN_POD_UPDATE_0      TYPE C,
        EF_ERROR_IN_INTERFACE_0       TYPE C,
        EF_ERROR_IN_GOODS_ISSUE_0     TYPE C,
        EF_ERROR_IN_FINAL_CHECK_0     TYPE C.


  SELECT * FROM LIPS INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE LT_LIPS
      WHERE VGBEL = LT_BCODE_I-VGBEL
      AND VGPOS = LT_BCODE_I-VGPOS. 
LOOP AT LT_LIPS INTO WA_LIPS.
              WA_LIPS-LFIMG = LT_BCODE_I-MENGE.
              MODIFY LT_LIPS FROM WA_LIPS INDEX SY-TABIX.
            ENDLOOP.

             "VBPOK IS CHANGE INDICATOR, AFTERWARD CALL FUNCTION TO CHANGE FIELD LFIMG IN STANDART TABLE LIPS.
             LOOP AT LT_LIPS INTO GT_LIPS.
               LT_VBPOK-LFIMG = GT_LIPS-LFIMG.
               APPEND LT_VBPOK.
             ENDLOOP.
            ls_vbkok-vbeln_vl   = LT_BCODE_I-REF_DOC.
            CALL FUNCTION 'WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE'
              EXPORTING
                vbkok_wa                    = ls_vbkok    " DELIVERY DOCUMENT NUMBER
                synchron                    = 'X'
                no_messages_update          = ' '
                update_picking              = 'X'
                commit                      = 'X'
                delivery                    = LT_BCODE_I-REF_DOC   "VARIABLE OF DELIVERY DOCUMENT
                nicht_sperren               = 'X'
                if_error_messages_send_0    = space
              IMPORTING
                ef_error_any_0              = ef_error_any_0
                ef_error_in_item_deletion_0 = ef_error_in_item_deletion_0
                ef_error_in_pod_update_0    = ef_error_in_pod_update_0
                ef_error_in_interface_0     = ef_error_in_interface_0
                ef_error_in_goods_issue_0   = ef_error_in_goods_issue_0
                ef_error_in_final_check_0   = ef_error_in_final_check_0
              TABLES
                vbpok_tab                   = lt_vbpok     "TABLE TO BE CHANGE
                prot                        = lt_prot.
```

Comment: What does the log (Table prot = lt_prot) say? All the error fields (ef_error_...) are empty?

Comment: did you look at the messages you got back from WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE? The protocol table PROT should contain warnings and errors that should point you in the right direction. The first thing that jumps out to me is that you're not setting the item number in LT_VBPOK, you're only setting LFIMG.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai How to check the Table prot? sorry newbie here

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek how to make the setting?

Comment: @NGSUITYAN place a breakpoint right after the function module call and you can see what is in table lt_prot

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai done update the question, is that missing the vbeln_vl? but I ady mention it before call the function... no sure what happen...

Comment: did you check exporting parameters ` ef_error_xxxxxxxx`? any of them are non-empty?

Comment: @Suncatcher  yes it already stated in the question, i applied in screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this function model has the status "Not released" on its attribute tab. That means that **it should not be used in customer code**, because

1. SAP might change or delete it in a future update without warning, and then your code won't work anymore.
2. It is very likely not properly documented.
3. It might have hidden and unexpected gotchas. Like for example only working for specific corner-cases, not doing everything you would expect it to be doing or requiring to call some other function module before or afterwards in order to do something.
4. The error handling might be missing or might provide information that's misleading outside of the context where the module is usually used

So before you use a "Not Released" function module, you should check the transaction code `BAPI` if there is an official bapi function module which does what you want. Bapi function modules are specifically intended for use in customer code. They are well-documented, are guaranteed to take care of everything and SAP promises not to break them in future updates.

---

So much for the preaching, let's look at your actual problem.

Whenever you encounter a data structure with fields like `MSGNO`, `MSGTY`, `MSGID` and up to four generic variables, you are dealing with a message. You can look up message codes like that in transaction `SE91`. There we can see that the number 280 in message class VL means:

> Required field in interface to delivery update missing VBELN 00000 00000

This could refer to the structure `ls_vbkok` or to the table `lt_vbpok`. I would recommend you to set a debugger breakpoint in your code and find out where that VBELN field could be missing a value.

Comment: As I said, I would check in the debugger if all the fields are filled before the `CALL FUNCTION`. But as I wrote, it's an unreleased function module, so it can have all kinds of weird undocumented constraints. Sometimes you have to debug them yourself to find out what's actually wrong.

Comment: Is that means more proper to use BAPI rather than FM?

Comment: BAPIs are function modules too. But yes, given the choice, you should always prefer to use a BAPI over a non-released function module you picked up somewhere in the standard code.